# Does intent go queue when calling startService for IntentService multiple times?

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I want to download from internet with a `IntentService`. I pass a url through `Intent` to `IntentService` by calling `startService(intentserive);`.

If I call `startService` for a various intents, do the intents go queue for download?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short answer to your question is YES. From the docs:

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work.
>
> This "work queue processor" pattern is commonly used to offload tasks
>   from an application's main thread. The IntentService class exists to
>   simplify this pattern and take care of the mechanics. To use it,
>   extend IntentService and implement onHandleIntent(Intent).
>   IntentService will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and
>   stop the service as appropriate.
>
> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

[Official docs link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Intent service queues all the work intents and process them one by one in single worker thread.